# opencv viedeocapture memory leak

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks

I am nearly done with my OpenCV project and I think I've found a memory leak in cv::VideoCapture.

I reduce the code to the following minimum example and after 1000 iterations the process grows to around 40MB. If I take pictures its even more, but to keep it a simple Demo I just open the cam and close it.

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
int temp_counter=0;
while(true)
{

    cap.open(0);
    cap.release();
    temp_counter++;
    std::cout << " Nr. " << temp_counter << '\n';
}
```

I searched and tested for hours but with no results.

Does anybody have any suggestions on where the issue could be?

EDIT:

I use 2.4.9 and tested it on a
Win7 32bit with logitech c920 Cams
and on a Win8 32bit netbook with the build in webcam 
and on both systems the memory of the programm raises until it crash after ca. 3000-5000 iterations 
next step is to test it with vanguard

Comment: Since it doesn't happen here, I'll bet it is a bug in your video camera's driver or in platform-specific portions of opencv. Did you try a standard memory leak profiler such as `valgrind`?

Comment: please add opencv version / os (btw, could not reproduce on 2.4.9/xp)

Comment: I was able to reproduce a leak on OS X Mavericks with version 2.4.9. It appears to be originating in platform-specific code though, so the cause may not be the same.